# why does it take two clicks for the DOM view to appear

Tags: html, dom

0

this is my code now

template file:

<quill-view-html [content]="question.questionText" format="html" theme="snow" [id]="question.id" [change]="loadAnswer(studentAnswer)"

.ts file:

loadAnswer(studentAnswer) {

```
  if (document.getElementById(question.id)) {
  let inputs = 
  document.getElementById(question.id).getElementsByTagName('input') || [];
  inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
     input.value = studentAnswer[index]
  })
}
```

}
the answer gets display in the input box but i am not able to type a new answer over it since the previous answer gets coming back. Any solution to this?

Comment: I cannot understand the question, and from this code it does not look like you are using Angular at all. Also you need to share the relevant part of your template.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's make your code more pretty.

```
   loadAnswer(studentAnswer){
          if (document.getElementById(question.id)) {
          let inputs = document.getElementById(question.id).getElementsByTagName('input') || [];
          inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
             input.value = studentAnswer[index]
          })
        }
      }
```

Can you share your template code with us? Function looks good.

Comment: <quill-view-html [content]="questionText" format="html" theme="snow" [id]="question.id">
          </quill-view-html> {{loadAnswer(question)}}

Comment: This function does not return any value. You should not use {{ }}. Try (change)="loadAnswer(question)" in the editor.